# /etc/thnuclnt/.thnumod - what is that file for?

Tags: rootkit

```
~ > sudo  find / -user root -perm -4000 -ls
710826   44 -rwsr-xr--   1 root     messagebus    42500 Окт  3 22:31 /lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
658951  464 -rwsr-xr-x   1 root     root       472124 Июл 28  2011 /etc/thnuclnt/.thnumod
...
```

and

```
~ > ll /etc/thnuclnt/.thnumod
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 462K 2011-07-28 18:12 /etc/thnuclnt/.thnumod*
~ > file /etc/thnuclnt/.thnumod
/etc/thnuclnt/.thnumod: setuid ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.4.1, stripped
```

Comment: Why is this tagged rootkit? BTW. It seems to belong to vmware.

Comment: But why hidden binary in /etc ? It is statically linked. And so few references from Google ?
**Also dpkg doesn't know of it**. It looks strange.